# Facebook Audience Network Mediation via MoPub (Banner and Interstitial Ads)

Tags: android-studio, mopub, facebook-audience-network

I'm trying to mediate Facebook Audience Network via MoPub but I don't have any native ads setup. I only want to mediate banner and interstitial ads. In the MoPub documentation there's no instruction for banner and interstitial ads, only native and native banner ads.

So, I went ahead and simply added:

```
implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:facebookaudiencenetwork:5.5.0.8'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.6.0'
```

to my app: build.gradle
then I initialized the Audience Network SDK inside onCreate method.

```
AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
```

Then I created a HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> facebookConfig = new HashMap<>();
facebookConfig.put("banner", "");
facebookConfig.put("interstitial", "”);
```

and passed the hashmap to sdkconfiguration mediation settings:

```
SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("AD_UNIT_ID");
sdkConfiguration.withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(FacebookAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), facebookConfig);
sdkConfiguration.withLegitimateInterestAllowed(false).build();
```

What am I missing here?

Here's the error I'm getting in Studio:

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity in.techpop.squarifymyphotos.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$1@8492337 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity in.techpop.squarifymyphotos.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$1@8492337 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1588)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1368)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1515)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1488)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1476)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.registerScreenStateBroadcastReceiver(MoPubView.java:193)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:155)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at in.techpop.squarifymyphotos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Calling AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this); is not needed. This is called from FacebookAdapterConfiguration.class.

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The exception your getting is just from the MoPubView or MoPubInterstitial not calling #destroy in actvities onDestroy() method.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    moPubView.destroy(); }
    moPubInterstitial.destroy();
}
```

Comment: I'm calling it inside onDestroy() method. I'm actually first checking if it's null and then destroying if its not null.